# Can someone prove to me if this inequality with norms and dot products holds?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, triangle-inequality

Can someone show me if the following inequality holds ($\cdot$ is multiplication)?

$\|a\|\cdot\|b\| \le \frac{1}{2}(\|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2)$

I am sure the following holds ($\bullet$ is dot product):

$a\bullet b \le \frac{1}{2}(||a||^2 + ||b||^2)$

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $(x-y)^2\geq 0$  with $x=\|a\|$ and  $y=\|b\|$ .

Comment: $(a-b)^2\geq 0\implies  ab\leq \frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Surb  Ok clear, I thought this formula was only valid for scalars. I got a bit confused by the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Comment: @C-RAM good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(||a|| - ||b||)^2 = ||a||^2 - 2||a||||b|| + ||b||^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow ||a||^2 + ||b||^2 \geq 2||a||||b||$